# React-native : null is not an object(evaluating 'RNFSMANAGER.RNFSFileTypeRegular')

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error as soon as I add this line to my App.js in react-native project.

```
import * as RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
```

> null is not an object(evaluating 'RNFSMANAGER.RNFSFileTypeRegular')

I am attaching the screens that I get. 
First I get :

[image]

then it quickly converts into :

[image]

I also tried to link react-native fs using:

[image]

I don't know if i have to do this but when I try to do yarn add `react-native-fs`.

[image]

Though I was able to do :
[image]

Comment: Is this with RN 0.60+? From 0.60 onward supposedly you don't need to link anymore but this error (in the past) means you need to link. I see the same thing as well with RN 0.60.4 testing on Android (iOS works fine for me after `pod install`)

Answer (score 4):

Install react-native-fs : `npm install --save react-native-fs`

Then restart project : `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and here's how I resolved.
To see the details of the issue, open the workspace file in iOS and try to run the simulator. I'll pop up an error. 
For me, an embedded library was missing. 
Not sure WHY but it sometimes happen when you install other dependencies using npm or yarn.

So, I just ran

`npm install`

Then

`cd ios`
`pod install`

And that was it for my case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've done the perfect installation. If your link succeeds without error, you can try this.

`var RNFS = require("react-native-fs");`

And once you've done that, you shouldn't do that again. The same code can be duplicated.

Comment: You can try `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: If this does not work, it means the link is not working properly. Make sure it's working properly.

Comment: 1) I am using expo. Is there a corresponding command for expo? 
warning: the transform cache was reset.
result of your command :
Loading dependency graph, done.
And then it just sits there.

2)How can we make sure link is working properly?

I tried your command and while it sits there on a separate terminal started expo but ended with the same result

Comment: The command I wrote in my answer is the one used in Expo. If you run the link normally. A message should be displayed that the link was executed normally. But nothing seems to be in sight and it's not working as expected. Try installing manually or updating the response native command version to the latest and try the link again `npm install -g react-native-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

On android, after linking, I had to manually add `new RNFSPackage()` to getPackages in `MainApplication.java`